# AWK - Delete Duplicate Lines - exclude field 2 from having to match

Tags: awk

I need to know how to delete duplicate lines, but excluding a field from having to match (field2 in this case).  AWK would be preferred.

**Input:**

```
LSP1    1000    NODE1   NODE2   NODE3
LSP1    2000    NODE1   NODE2   NODE3
LSP2    3000    NODE1   NODE2
LSP2    2500    NODE3
LSP3    4000    NODE1   NODE2   NODE3   NODE4   
LSP3    4000    NODE1   NODE2
```

**Output:**

```
LSP2    3000    NODE1   NODE2
LSP2    2500    NODE3
LSP3    4000    NODE1   NODE2   NODE3   NODE4   
LSP3    4000    NODE1   NODE2
```

Comment: Why is `LSP1` deleted,  `$2` doesnt match? Your post needs more details.

Comment: Looks like every one got @jww-ed. Upvoting to compensate...

Answer (score 1):

`awk` assisted `uniq` solution.  `uniq` can skip fields but has to be from the beginning; a helper `awk` script swaps the first two fields; called afterwards to put back in the same order.

```
$ function s12() { awk '{t=$1;$1=$2;$2=t}1' </dev/stdin; }; s12 <file | uniq -uf1 | s12

LSP2 3000 NODE1 NODE2
LSP2 2500 NODE3
LSP3 4000 NODE1 NODE2 NODE3 NODE4
LSP3 4000 NODE1 NODE2
```

Answer (score 1):

```
awk '{t=$0; $2=""; a[$0]=t; b[$0]++; c[NR]=$0} 
      END {for (i in c) if (b[c[i]]==1) print a[c[i]]}'
```

The idea is to remove the second field from `$0` and store it in `t`.  Then we build up a hash `a` of the original lines, a hash `b` where we count occurrences of the line without the second field and a hash `c` of line-number to line-without-field-two values so that we can reproduce the original order.

At the end, for every line number (`for (i in c)`), we check how many times that line (with the second field removed) occurred in the file (`b[c[i]]`).  If it was exactly once, then we print the original value (`a[c[i]]`).

Comment: you can replace `sub(" "$2, " ")` with `$2=""` .

Comment: @karakfa Good point, changed the answer.

Comment: You have 5 variables all with single-character names. Your code would be vastly easier to understand if you added a couple more characters to each and made them each something meaningful.

Answer (score -1):

If you don't care about output order:

```
$ cat tst.awk
{
    orig0     = $0
    $2        = ""
    key       = $0
    vals[key] = orig0
    cnt[key]++
}
END {
    for ( key in cnt ) {
        if ( cnt[key] == 1 ) {
            print vals[key]
        }
    }
}

$ awk -f tst.awk file
LSP2    2500    NODE3
LSP2    3000    NODE1   NODE2
LSP3    4000    NODE1   NODE2
LSP3    4000    NODE1   NODE2   NODE3   NODE4
```

If you do:

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file
$ cat tst.awk
{
    orig0 = $0
    $2    = ""
    key   = $0
}
++cnt[key] == 1 {
    keys[++numKeys] = key
    vals[key] = orig0
}
END {
    for ( keyNr=1; keyNr<=numKeys; keyNr++ ) {
        key = keys[keyNr]
        if ( cnt[key] == 1 ) {
            print vals[key]
        }
    }
}

$ awk -f tst.awk file
LSP2    3000    NODE1   NODE2
LSP2    2500    NODE3
LSP3    4000    NODE1   NODE2   NODE3   NODE4
LSP3    4000    NODE1   NODE2
```